# how hide button if have same name with different field based on user selection

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-view

For example below mentioned code

```xml
<button name="invoice_recreate" string="Recreate Invoice"/> 
<button name="invoice_corrected" string="Ignore Exception" />
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to get this working?

Comment: Hide Buttons of same name in same view. For example
<button name="invoice_recreate"  string="Recreate Invoice"/>
<button name="invoice_corrected"string="Ignore Exception" />

Comment: Can you please explain properly ?? So, we can understand what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Add the field selection to the view and the attrs attribute to the button like this:

```xml
<field name="selection_field" invisible="1" />

<button name="invoice_recreate"
        string="Recreate Invoice"
        attrs="{'invisible': [('selection_field', '=', 'value')]}" /> 

<button name="invoice_corrected"
        string="Ignore Exception"
        attrs="{'invisible': [('selection_field', '!=', 'value')]}" />
```

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for, let me know if you are asking anything different